# Validate hmac with hashed stored key

Tags: hash, key-management, authorization, validation, hmac

What if an HMAC is correctly generated and sent with the data to the server, so far I know the server needs to know the original data with which the MAC was created in order to re-create the MAC and compare, but in this scenario the server has everything except that the key is hashed and not stored "plain". How can the server validate the MAC?

Comment: You can't that's the point, it verifies that the HMAC was generated from a particular set of data with a particular key. Well, with a high probability. Chances of collisions are low if done properly.

Comment: Anyone verifying the HMAC must *also* know the secret key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The significant difference between a (H)MAC and a hash is the key component. The idea of a MAC is, that it should only be possible to generate a specific MAC for a specific input by knowing a specific key. So if someone can generate a specific (given) MAC output for a given message input, he proves having the same key that was used to generate the given MAC output.

In other words: If someone calculates the MAC `x` of the message `m` by using the key `k` (but only publishes `m`), everybody who can generate `x` proves to have knowledge about the key `k`.

To answer your question: If you *need* to generate the MAC without having the key on your server, you probably want to use a hash instead of a MAC.

Comment: Or the server must also know the secret key.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the key, you can't generate the HMAC. That's the whole point of a HMAC - it's a quick way to provide message integrity using existing key material. If you could regenerate the HMAC without the key, an attacker could simply generate a HMAC for a different message and alter the payload.

Comment: my question was edited and lose the sense, what I wanted to say is: if the server has all the data needed to re-generate the HMAC but the key is stored hashed not "plain". Is there anyway to validate and compare the HMAC sent to the server ?

Comment: No. If you hash the key, you can't use it. You no longer have the key at that point.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a kind-of [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) which is such that it can be verified by using a "transformed key" which is itself not sufficient to *compute* other MAC values, then you do not want a MAC. What you want is a [digital signature algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature). One way to describe a digital signature algorithm is the following: it is like a MAC where the key for *generating* new MAC values, and the key for *verifying* a MAC value with regards to some data, are distinct. The two keys are mathematically linked with each other (the verification key works for MAC values which were generating with the corresponding generation key, and none other), but it is not feasible to recompute the generation key from the verification key. The verification key can thus be made *public*, while the generation key is kept *private*.

The most widely used signature algorithm is [RSA](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125) (RSA is actually *two* algorithms, one for encryption and one for signatures; I am talking about the one for signatures; both algorithms share the same core mathematical operation, but are still quite different in their usage details).

[HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) is *not* a digital signature algorithm (despite what sloppy terminologists occasionally pretend).